# Decode the access token from JWT Format

Tags: lua, oauth-2.0, jwt, decode, openid-connect

We are using nginx server for reverse proxying with openresty openid lua installed.... This means that every request has an Authorization header containing JWT token -  access id and refresh token.

Now, what we need to do is decode the access token because I need the sub from the JWT token and log it on nginx server.

Is there a way to decode and log JWT? I looked into the openidc.lua file and I can see that it decodes the id token but I can't see where I can decode the access token.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This done the trick for me

```
local jwt = require "resty.jwt"
local jwt_obj = jwt:load_jwt(res.access_token)
local cjson = require "cjson"
ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, "res.access_token.sub=", cjson.encode(jwt_obj))
```